# Internal Hard Drive Switcher

Tags: hard-disk, sata

Does there exist a cable where I can plug two hard drives into the same motherboard's sata slot and with the flip of a switch (between power-offs) switch between these two hard drives (without having to physically unplug anything)?

I'm not interested in any other solution but the existence of what I'm describing (no USB, eSATA, bios, or bootloader answers please).

Comment: So two devices on one SATA cable, with the on/off determined by which device has power?     Nope, I think you need to relearn how Serial-ATA functions compared to Parallel-ATA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a million years, I would have never thought that this existed. But.. [The Sata Switch is a thing.](http://www.cooldrives.com/index.php/4posaiisw3ba.html) This model, can hold 4 different SATA3 drives. 
 [image]

I read the product description and information, and it seems like it will do everything you are looking to do, for the cool price of 79.00.

Literally cuts the power from the unused drives, I'm assuming you have to power off/switch HDD/Power on in order to get this to work correctly, but its a pretty cool little device.

Only one sata cable goes to your motherboard.

Comment: Totally better than my answer, but something tells me OP may still not be satisfied, as it does not meet his very specific cable that will detect which device has power lol.

Comment: @NZKshatriya Yea, that cable doesn't exist. Unless OP makes one himself, but even then he is going to frying hard drives the entire time. If his goal is to have a single sata port on the mobo be able to access multiple drives separately from one another... this is his best bet.

Comment: Usually, when I imagine something that is possible, it already exists. I tried buying this from two different sources, but both couldn't process my credit card when it came time to place the order. I also see them on ebay (from Germany) at a significantly higher price. I wish Amazon had these (they never have issues with my card).

Comment: wow really this thing exist!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that can address your situation, but you will have to be a little flexible, due to the fact your desired cable fix does not exist.

[Kingwin HDD Power Switch Module 6 Switches for 5.25-Inch Bay](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00TZR3E70)

Idea is simple.  Have HDD/SSDs connected to each SATA port on the board, and have power distributed to each drive via the switch module.

You can manually turn any device not in use off, and of course turn it back on when you need it.